# Image is saved as tmp file while trying to uploaded it with symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, file-upload

I am new at Symfony. I wanted to create a reusable form where i can upload images. I have read the documentation. But every time i upload an image it is saved as .tmp file and not in the path i give. I have been trying for three days now and have no idea what i am doing wrong :( Any opinion is highly appreciated. :)

Entity
`

```
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;

/**
 * image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="media")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="test\ImageBundle\Entity\Image    \imageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class image
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="path",type="string",length= 255, nullable=true)
 */
public $path;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="alt",type="string",length= 255, nullable=true)
 */
private $ImageAlt;

/**
 * Image file
 *
 * @var File
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "5M",
 *     mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/tiff"},
 *     maxSizeMessage = "The maxmimum allowed file size is 5MB.",
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "Only the filetypes image are allowed."
 * )
 */
protected $file;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=1024)
 */
private $content;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=128)
 */
private $url;



public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __dir__.'/../../../../web/uploads';
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

public function getAssetPath()
{
    return 'uploads/'.$this->path;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    $this->oldFile = $this->getPath();


    if (null !== $this->file)
        $this->path = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(),true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(),$this->path);
        unset($this->file);

        if ($this->oldFile != null) unlink($this->tempFile);
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function preRemoveUpload()
{
    $this->tempFile = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if (file_exists($this->tempFile)) unlink($this->tempFile);
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getPath()
{
    return $this->path;
}

/**

public function getName()
{
var_dump($this->name);
return $this->name;
}
 */
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageAlt()
{
    return $this->ImageAlt;
}

/**
 * @param string $ImageAlt
 */
public function setImageAlt($ImageAlt)
{
    $this->ImageAlt = $ImageAlt;
}


/**
 * Set content
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return image
 */
public function setContent($content)
{
    $this->content = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set url
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @return image
 */
public function setUrl($url)
{
    $this->url = $url;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get url
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUrl()
{
    return $this->url;
}
```

}
`

Form

```
  <?php

namespace test\ImageBundle\Form\Image;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class imageType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('path','file',array(
            'label' => 'Image',
            'required' => true
        ))
        ->add('ImageAlt')
        ->add('content')
        ->add('url')
    ;
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'test\ImageBundle\Entity\Image\image'
    ));
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'test_imagebundle_image_image';
}
```

}

Controller

```
<?php

namespace test\ImageBundle\Controller\Image;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use test\ImageBundle\Entity\Image\image;
use test\ImageBundle\Form\Image\imageType;

/**
 * Image\image controller.
 *
 * @Route("/image")
 */
class imageController extends Controller
{

/**
 * Lists all Image\image entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="image")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('testImageBundle:Image\image')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    );
}
/**
 * Creates a new Image\image entity.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="image_create")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("testImageBundle:Image\image:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entities= new image();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entities);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($entities);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->get('router')->generate($request->get('_route')));


    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entities,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a form to create a Image\image entity.
 *
 * @param image $entity The entity
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createCreateForm(image $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new imageType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('image_create'),
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

    return $form;
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Image\image entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="image_new")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new image();
    $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Image\image entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="image_show")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('testImageBundle:Image\image')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Image\image entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Image\image entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="image_edit")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('testImageBundle:Image\image')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Image\image entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
* Creates a form to edit a Image\image entity.
*
* @param image $entity The entity
*
* @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
*/
private function createEditForm(image $entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new imageType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('image_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ));

    $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

    return $form;
}
/**
 * Edits an existing Image\image entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="image_update")
 * @Method("PUT")
 * @Template("testImageBundle:Image\image:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('testImageBundle:Image\image')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Image\image entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('image_edit', array('id' => $id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
/**
 * Deletes a Image\image entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}", name="image_delete")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('testImageBundle:Image\image')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Image\image entity.');
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('image'));
}

/**
 * Creates a form to delete a Image\image entity by id.
 *
 * @param mixed $id The entity id
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
 */
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('image_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

`getUploadRootDir()` - are you sure it is correct path and folder exist with proper permissions? Take a look at https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle - it saves your next three days.

Comment: I dont want to use any extra bundles for uploading images